# MySQL database optimization for 20.000 users or more

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

I have been looking for some optimization tips since I´m doing a RPG modification which uses MySQL to store data by PHP.

I´m using one unique table to store all user information in columns by his unique ID, and I have to store (many?) data for each user. Weapons and other information.

I´m using explode and implode as a method to store the weapons, for example, in one column with the 'text' value. I don´t know if that´s a good practice and I don´t know if I will have performance problems if I get thousands of players doing tons of UPDATES , SELECT , etc, requests.

I read that a Junction table may be better to store the weapons and all those information, but I don´t know if that will get better information that you request it by the explode method.

I mean, I should store all the weapons in a different table, each weapon with his information (each weapon have some information, like different columns, I use multiple explode for that inside the main explode) and the user owner of that weapon to identify the weapon than just have them in one column.

It can be 100 items at least to store, I don´t know if it´s good to make 100 records per user on a different table and call all of them all the time better than just call the column and use explode.

Also I want to improve my skills and knowledge to make the best performance MySQL database I can.

I hope somebody can tell me something.

Thanks, and sorry for my stupid english grammar.

Comment: You should do some reading on database normalization and how to join tables. What you are doing will mean that you are requiring code to separate the weapons. If the site gets bigger, this will become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: As a general rule, it's better to have millions of properly indexed rows than thousands of badly indexed ones. Imagine a query to find who has a particular weapon - with a junction table, it's easy. With explode/implode, you have to compute stuff across every row in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost always best practice to normalize your table data.  There are some exceptions to this rule (especially in very high volume databases), but you probably do not need to worry about those exceptions until you get to the point of first understanding how to properly normalize and index your tables.

Typically, try to arrange your tables in a way that mimics real-world objects and their relations to each other.

So, in your case you have users - that is one table. Each user might have multiple weapons.  So, you now have a weapons table.  Since multiple different users might have the same weapon and each user might have multiple weapons, you have a many-to-many relationship between them, so you should have a table "users_weapons" or similar that does nothing but relate user id's to weapon id's.

Now say the users can all have armor.  So now you add an armor table and a users_armor table (as this is likely many-to-many as well).

Just think through the different aspects of your game and try to understand the relationships between them. Make sure you can model these relationships in database tables before you even bother writing any code to actually implement the functionality.

Comment: Thanks mate. But, if I have one table with user information and user ID, one table for weapons with weapon ID and all, I need to make a 3rd table with something else? I have to add the user ID too in the weapon´s table?

Comment: No, the weapons table would not have a user id at all.  The only way to relate the users to their weapons would be through the user_weapons table. The user_weapons table would only need two fields (with compound primary key) - user_id and weapon_id.

Comment: The thing is that you are assuming that I want that table to define the weapons, but that´s not the case. I want a make an inventory for the weapons, which are already defined through PHP. So, there is an ammount and ID of the item, and the owner (player id). It´s still the same case then? Thanks for all.

Comment: So the weapons aren't a database table?  That seems really odd, and probably a bit of a problem later on as you want to add more weapons (much easier to do in database than if it is hard-coded).  If you want an amounts column simple add it you user_weapons to where is has 3 columns (user_id, weapon_id, weapon_quantity).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is better to use several tables instead of one. It's better to db performance, easier to understand, easier to maintain and simplier to use as well.

Let's suggest that one user has several weapons with multiple features(but not unique among all weapons). And in one place in your game you just need to know the value of one specific feature:

- doing it by your way you'll need to find user row in users table, fetch on column, explode it several times, and there you have your value, but it complicates even more if you want to change it and save then.
- better way is having one table for user details(login, password, email etc), another table which keeps user weapons(name of weapon, image maybe) and table in which will be all features, special powers of weapons kept. You could keep all possible features of all weapons in extra table as well. This way you if you already know user id from user table, you'll have to only join 2 tables in your sql query, and there you got value of feature of specific weapon of user.

Example pseudo schema of tables:

```
users
    user_id
    user_name
    password
    email

weapons
    weapon_id
    user_id
    weapon_name
    image

weapons_features
    feature_id
    weapon_id
    feature_name
    feature_value
```

And if you really want to use some ordered data in text field in database encode it to `JSON` or `serialize` it. This way you don't have to explode and implode it!

Comment: I would suggest that you need to remove user_id from weapons altogether and have a users_weapons table that better represents the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I know it. I just want to provide a little simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

As all guys said, typically you should start from normalized database structure.
If performance is ok, then great, nothing to do.

If not, you can try many different things:

1. Find and optimize query which works slow.
2. Denormalize queries - sometimes joins kill performance.
3. Change data access pattern used in application.
4. Store data in file system or use NoSQL/polyglot persistence solution.